# C# - Create Windows Firewall rule with multi profile

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I'm using **INetFwRule** to create a windows firewall rule. I want this rule will apply with both domain & private profile but public profile. But the **Profiles** property does not support.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The INetFwRule expects multiple profiles to be ORed together. For example, to create a windows firewall rule that is enabled for both Domain and Private, you would need to do the following:

`INetFwRule2 rule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
rule.Profiles = (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE | (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN;`

If you are wanting to enable it for all profiles, you don't need to OR all 3 profiles together as there is an ALL flag:

`INetFwRule2 rule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
rule.Profiles = (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_ALL;`